# Type Error : Unhashable type: 'slice' [python] [dictionaries]

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror, python-3.9

```
os.chdir("Güvenlik_Hesaplar")
files = ''
dictionary = {}
ant = os.listdir()
dict_number = 1
i = 0 

while i < len(ant): # If the variable 'i' is less than the length of my files
    dictionary["{}" : ant[i].format(dict_number)] #e.g = '1': 'myfile.txt'
    dict_number += 1
    i += 1
```

Error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Barış\Desktop\Python\prg.py", line 20, in passwordrequest
 dictionary["{}" : ant[i].format(dict_number)]
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Can you help me to solve this, please? I am using Windows x64

Comment: You are trying to insert into `dictionary` with key as `dict_number` and value as `ant[i]`? Then just do `dictionary[str(dict_number)] = ant[i]`. Also you can remove `dict_number` as it is always `i` + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just add an entry in `dictionary` with `dict_number` as key and `ant[i]` as value, you can just do -

```
while i < len(ant):
    dictionary[str(dict_number)] = ant[i]
    ....
```

The problem in your code `dictionary["{}" : ant[i].format(dict_number)]` is that `"{}" : ant[i]....` is treated as a slice and that is used to fetch value from `dictionary`. To fetch it, the key (i.e. `"{}" : ant[i]...`) is hashed first. So, python is throwing the error.

You can remove `dict_number` from your code as it is always `i` + 1. This can be done using `enumerate` and for loop.

```
for dict_number, file in enumerate(ant, start=1):
    dictionary[str(dict_number)] = file
```

Here `enumerate` returns the index as well as the element of the list `ant` and `start=1` will enforce that the index will start from 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to do it:

```py
import os

os.chdir("Güvenlik_Hesaplar")
dictionary = {str(k + 1): filename for k, filename in enumerate(os.listdir())}
```